# Can't start BIND9 | Requests repeated too quickly

Tags: server, dns, systemd, bind

I'm having a problem when starting BIND9 using `sudo systemctl start bind9`. I get a random error and when I examine it with `sudo systemctl status bind9`, I get this:

```
bind9.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start BIND Domain Name Server.
bind9.service: Schedule restart job, restart counter is at 20.
Stopped BIND Domain Name Server.
bind9.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
```

I set `DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec` and `DefaultStartLimitBurst` to 40s and 20 respectively on `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, so I know it's not because the start requests are coming too quickly (I reloaded with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` afterwards).

This is what the logs on `/var/log/kern.log` show but I'm new to Linux so I don't know how to recognize and solve the error based on that:

```
...apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open profile="named" name="/proc/cmdline" pid=8226 comm="named" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

...apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open profile="named" name="/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease" pid=8232 comm="named" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

And this is is my `/etc/systemd/system/bind9.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=BIND Domain Name Server
Documentation=man:named(8)
After=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/named
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/rndc reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rndc stop
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=bind9.service
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Taking as a guidance the `denied_mask=r` from the logs, I added to the `named` profile on `apparmor` (`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named`), the two path from the errors with the masks where they were denied for (r):

- `/proc/cmdline` as `@{PROC}/cmdline r`
- `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease` as `@{PROC}/sys/kernel/osrelease r`

And now the error that I get in the logs is:

```
...appamor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="syslog-ng" pid=9486 common="apparmor_parser"
```

And stopping or disabling `apparmor` with `sudo systemctl stop|disable apparmor` doesn't solve the issue either.

(In case I wasn't supposed to do this modification, please let me know and I'll revert the changes)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If it's 18.04 or older, then you may not be able to use `DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec` and will need to instead update the `bind9.service` file to use `StartLimitIntervalSec` ...

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 @matigo